# Pandas: Drop duplicate but consecutive rows and keep the first row within group

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['James', 'James', 'James', 'James',
           'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max', 'Max',
           'Park', 'Park','Park', 'Park',
           'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'],
    'From_num': [578, 420, 420, 'Started', 298, 78, 36, 298, 'Started', 28, 28, 311, 'Started', 60, 520, 99, 'Started'],
    'To_num': [96, 578, 578, 420, 36, 298, 78, 36, 298, 112, 112, 28, 311, 150, 60, 520, 99],
    'Date': ['2020-05-12', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-01', '2019-06-18',
             '2019-08-26', '2019-06-20', '2019-01-30', '2018-10-23',
             '2018-08-29', '2020-05-21', '2020-05-20', '2019-11-22',
             '2019-04-12', '2019-10-16', '2019-08-26', '2018-12-11', '2018-10-09']})
```

And I wish to drop only the CONSECUTIVE row (ignore the 'Date' field) within each ID group, for example line 1 and 2 have the same value, and wish to drop the 2nd duplicate, same as line 9 and line 10, drop line 10, the df is like this:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
2   James      420     578  2020-02-01 # Drop the this duplicated row (ignore date)
3   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
4     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
5     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
6     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
7     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
8     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
9    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
10   Park       28     112  2020-05-20 # Drop this duplicate row (ignore date)
11   Park      311      28  2019-11-22
12   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
13    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
14    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
15    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
16    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

I wrote loop conditions, but it is very redundant and slow, I assume there might be easier way to do this, so please help if you have ideas. Great thanks. The expected result is like this, please be aware that there are also two NON-consecutive values in Max, line 4 and 7, I wish to keep them both:

```
       ID  From_num  To_num    Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
8    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
9    Park      311      28  2019-11-22
10   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print( df[~(df.iloc[:,0:3] == df.iloc[:,0:3].shift()).all(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True) )
```

Prints:

```
       ID From_num  To_num        Date
0   James      578      96  2020-05-12
1   James      420     578  2020-02-02
2   James  Started     420  2019-06-18
3     Max      298      36  2019-08-26
4     Max       78     298  2019-06-20
5     Max       36      78  2019-01-30
6     Max      298      36  2018-10-23
7     Max  Started     298  2018-08-29
8    Park       28     112  2020-05-21
9    Park      311      28  2019-11-22
10   Park  Started     311  2019-04-12
11    Tom       60     150  2019-10-16
12    Tom      520      60  2019-08-26
13    Tom       99     520  2018-12-11
14    Tom  Started      99  2018-10-09
```

Comment: Thanks@Andrej Kesely, just wondering iloc[:, 0:3] it does not include the 3rd column right? only does col index from 0 to 2?

Comment: @JimmyXXLumix Yes that's right. You can also do `df.loc[:,'ID':'To_num']`

Answer (score 0):

with duckdb:

```
df1.sql().select("*,('{}-{}-{}').format(id,From_num,To_num) col1,lag(col1) over(order by index) lag2")\
    .select("*,sum(case when col1!=lag2 then 1 end) over(order by index) col2")\
    .select("*,row_number() over(partition by col2) col3").filter("col3=1")\
    .select("ID,From_num,To_num,Date")

┌─────────┬──────────┬────────┬────────────┐
│   ID    │ From_num │ To_num │    Date    │
│ varchar │ varchar  │ int64  │  varchar   │
├─────────┼──────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│ Tom     │ 60       │    150 │ 2019-10-16 │
│ Park    │ 28       │    112 │ 2020-05-21 │
│ Tom     │ 99       │    520 │ 2018-12-11 │
│ James   │ 578      │     96 │ 2020-05-12 │
│ Max     │ 36       │     78 │ 2019-01-30 │
│ Park    │ 311      │     28 │ 2019-11-22 │
│ Tom     │ Started  │     99 │ 2018-10-09 │
│ Max     │ 298      │     36 │ 2019-08-26 │
│ Max     │ 298      │     36 │ 2018-10-23 │
│ Park    │ Started  │    311 │ 2019-04-12 │
│ Max     │ Started  │    298 │ 2018-08-29 │
│ James   │ 420      │    578 │ 2020-02-02 │
│ James   │ Started  │    420 │ 2019-06-18 │
│ Max     │ 78       │    298 │ 2019-06-20 │
│ Tom     │ 520      │     60 │ 2019-08-26 │
├─────────┴──────────┴────────┴────────────┤
│ 15 rows                        4 columns │
```

└──────────────────────────────────────────┘